# How to structure a database with questions and answers?

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures

I am going to make a simple application that uses a database. I could need some guidance on how to structure it.

I shall make question program. What I have in mind is.

- One table with questions
- One table
  with the difficulity of the question
- One table with the category of the
  question

However, what do I do with the answers? Have them as seperate columns in the question-table? It sounds like a bad practice.(Also, where do I have the correct answer)

Each question will have 5 answers where only one of them is correct.

Comment: when deciding on tables all the information about a single object should be kept together...what additional information do you have about question difficulty that would require it to be in its own table instead of in the question table?  or are you saying that difficulty and category would be lookup tables and you would just store the FK in the question table?

Comment: Yes they would be foreign keys in the question table. Why would I repeat my self writing e.g. easy, medium, hard for difficulty on 500 questions? The same for categories, so my answer is yes, to your last question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer table.  Primary key can be (Question ID, Answer ID) where Answer ID can be, say, (a, b, c, d, e).  Other fields as seen fit, and also include a correct_answer binary field which is 1 for the question that is correct.

Comment: Thank you ryebr3ad for detailed quick and detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have a `answers` table with foreign key pointing to primary key of `questions` table

Comment: Thank you Nishant for instant reply:)

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep all your question data in one table? Something like:
`question_id | category_id | difficulty | correct_answer | question_text`
Where category_id is a foreign key to a 'Category' table, and correct_answer is a foreign key to the questions table.

For answers, you can do something like
`answer_id | question_id | answer_text | answer_order`
Question id is a foreign key pointing to the questions table - answer order is a number you can use to sort the answers for each question